# cache read system memory vs cpu read system memory

Tags: memory, arm, cpu-architecture, cpu-cache

On an arm based SoC running Android/Linux, I observed following:

1. Allocate a memory area as **un-cached** for device DMA input.  After DMA finishes, the content of this memory area is copied to another system memory area.
2. Alloc a memory area as **cached** for device DMA input.  After DMA finished, invalid the memory range, then copy the content of this memory area to anther system memory area.

The size of memory area allocated is about 2MB which is larger than the cache size (the L2 cache size is 256KB).

***method 2 is x10 faster than method 1***

That is: the memory copy operation of method 2 is x10 faster than method 1

I speculate that method 2 using cache read by **cache line size** from system memory when copying and the method 1 needs cpu read by **bus transaction size** from system memory bypassing the cache hardware.

However, I cannot find explicit explanation. I appreciate who can help providing detailed explaination.

Comment: isn't the issue simply down to "cached" version being able to serve all the subsequent requests through cached accesses whilst the uncached version has to fetch data through memory all the time.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many hardware items involved that it is difficult to give specifics.  The SOC determines a lot of this.  However, what you observe is typical in performance terms for modern ARM systems.

The main factor is [SDRAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR_SDRAM).  All DRAM is structured with 'rows' and 'columns'.<sup>[DRAM history](http://www.es.ele.tue.nl/premadona/files/akesson01.pdf)</sup>  On the DRAM chip, an entire 'row' can be read at one time.  Ie, there is a matrix of transistors and there is a physical point/wiring where an entire row can be read (in fact there maybe SRAM to store the ROW on the chip).  When you read another 'column', you need to 'un-charge/pre-charge' the wiring to access the new 'row'.  This takes some time.  The main point is that DRAM can read sequential memory very fast in large chunks.  Also, there is no command overhead as the memory streams out with each clock edge.

If you mark memory as un-cached, then a CPU/SOC may issue single beat reads.  Often these will 'pre-charge' consuming extra cycles during a single read/write and many extra commands must be sent to the DRAM device.

SDRAM also has 'banks'.  A bank has a separate 'ROW' buffer (static RAM/multi-transistor memory) which allows you to read from one bank to another without having to recharge/re-read.  The banks are often very far apart.  If your OS has physically allocated the 'un-cached' memory in a different bank from the 2<sup>nd</sup> 'cached' area, then this will also add an additional efficiency.  It common in an OS to manage cached/un-cached memory separately (for MMU issues).  The memory pools are often distant enough to be in separate banks.

Comment: as you metioned:If you mark memory as un-cached, then a CPU/SOC may issue single beat reads. how about the cached situation?I know it maybe depands on implementation,is there a common practice for the how data is read in(by cache controller)? thanks

Comment: Cache is either a hit (in the cache) or a miss.  If it is a miss, then it is put in the cache, but something must be evicted.  This is done by a 'way' mechanism and either random or LRU (last recent use) replacement.  However, for a `memcpy()`, cache doesn't matter.  You **DON'T** reuse data so the cache provide no benefit to a well written `memcpy()`.

Comment: The 'common practice' is always a cache line.  It is typically one or two SDRAM burst read/write sizes (not a row length).  You do not have to re-issue commands (pre-charge) is you read a row sequentially.  Typical maximum DDR bw is about the clock rate.  Ie, 16bit 500MHz DDR is about 1GB/s due to command overhead.